# Admob минимальное время показа?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, реклама, монетизация

Если я создам приложение в котором будет только баннер Admob (15 секунд показ) и запущу его на телефоне. Приложение будет публиковаться в маркете, но боюсь что Admob будет воспринимать его как накрутку показов. 
Приложение "Анекдоты", среднее время сеанса около 15-25 минут. Получается слишком много показов на одного пользователя. Возможно ли обезопасить себя от бана за накрутку?
Интересуют конкретные цифры.
Вопрос задается не для поиска способа обмануть, а потому что нужно добавить баннер с минимальным временем обновления

**"Больше показов больше прибыль" - Заказчик.**

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от типа банера. Если это нижний(верхний) банер на странице, то меньше 30 секунд вы его не выставите, в настройках admob при создании такого типа объявления явно указано, что минимальный период обновления - 30 секунд. Если же речь идет о межстраничном объявлении (показ на весь экран), там ограничений нет, но я бы не советовал показывать такой тип объявлений чаще чем 1 в минуту - это очень бесит пользователей, что влияет в конечном итоге на конверсию приложения и оценку в маркете.